# Listening for the custom event triggered from jQuery in Native Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I am triggering a custom event in jQuery using trigger function.

```
$(document.body).trigger("mycustomevent");
```

I can listen for the event using bind function, but I need to listen it using native functions without using jQuery.

Expecting some this like `document.body.addEventListener("mycustomevent", handleCustomEvent);`

My Problem :

I have included a.js in my page, it loads jQuery and b.js by inserting script tag in document. From main page I want to call the function defined in b.js. For that, a.js has to notify to main page that the b.js was loaded.

I want main page to handle it by listening for an event like `onBJSLoad`, don't want to call some dummy function as callback.

Comment: "But, i need to listen it using native functions without using jQuery" - why? Is this an assignment?

Comment: @David , I need to avoid the dependency of jquery plugin .

Comment: @bharati but you are already using jQuery to trigger the event :)

Comment: @David , I posted my real scenario .

Comment: @alex23 , Yeah I changed my code to addEventListener to trigger callback .

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a pretty bad idea to mix in custom events and also bring in the unecessary browser inconsistencies that comes with it.

Why not just do a callback, f.ex in in your main mapge:

```
window._onload = function() {
    // I’m ready
};
```

And then in a.js you can call it when the scripts are ready:

```
window._onload();
```